# Disabling selection in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that displays a list of days in a given month that looks like so:

[image: Program screenshot]

All the text boxes are set as `readonly`, which is the desired functionality.
While setting `enabled` to false works, it gives the control a blurred out look, which is difficult to override. In order to complete them, I want to keep the user from being able to select any text.

I have bound the `KeyUp` and `MouseUp` events in the following code:

```
private void dateDisplay_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.dateDisplay.SelectionStart = this.dateDisplay.Text.Length;
}

private void dateDisplay_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    this.dateDisplay.SelectionStart = this.dateDisplay.Text.Length;
}
```

where `dateDisplay` is the left `textbox`.

And this what the other `textbox` looks like with text selected, without being wired up to any events:

[image: Screenshot with selected text]

This code prevents the user from selecting any text inside the text boxes by forcing the cursor to end of the text box. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**DRY don't repeat yourself**

For each textbox you need to do the same, if you want the textbox's content to be unselectable.

So instead of calling for each textbox the shown code, you should refactor the code, by adding a method which does the same thing for any textbox.

Let us now focus on the code which should prevent the content to be selected.

```
this.dateDisplay.SelectionStart = this.dateDisplay.Text.Length;
```

If a user of the form clicks inside the textbox, e.g in the middle, an unexpected behaviour is shown, as the caret is moving magically to the end of the text.

A better way would be to use the `SelectionLength` property inside of these eventhandlers.
Setting the property to `0` will prevent the text to be selected, but the caret stays at the position.

The only proplem will be at the first time the form is shown, as neither of the 2 eventhandlers does fire.
Therfor you need to also use the `Shown` event.

**Refactoring**

Let us add a method `RemoveSelection` which takes an object as the inputparameter.

```
private void RemoveSelection(Object obj)
{
    TextBox textbox = obj as TextBox;
    if (textbox != null)
    {
        textbox.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
}
```

now we change the eventhandler's to

```
private void dateDisplay_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    RemoveSelection(sender);
}

private void dateDisplay_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    RemoveSelection(sender);
}
```

and add the `Shown` eventhandler

```
private void MyForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RemoveSelection(dateDisplay);
}
```

**Alternative way**

If you only want to show the desired values, you should use the right tool for the job.
Instead of a `TextBox` you should use a `Label` control. To simulate the appearance of a `TextBox` you need to set the properties:

```
BorderStyle= System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
AutoSize = false
Size.Height = 20
```

If the control which should be used, doesn't need to get the focus, then a `Label` is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. Unfortunately, due to the rows being displayed by adding a `UserControl`, there is no `Shown` event. I guess I can just set the focus to somewhere else on the main form...  I choose the first solution you provided, to enable the user to tab through the rows

Answer (score 5):

Another possible solution is to use a DataGridView.  You may define a column to be read only and it will appear as normal, i.e. not grayed out when the control is not enabled.  Plus I think a DataGridView would be a better solution overall given that you apparently want to displays rows of data.

Comment: if you were to expand this, it could be an answer

Comment: The best code is often code that doesn't exist at all. "Don't write that code at all; try a better approach altogether" is a valid way to improve a program. Precedent for such answers: [1](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/953/9357) [2](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1775/9357)

Comment: There are two reasons I choose this way over a DataGrid View. 1)The `Day` object (in linked question) is a complex object which proved difficult to display in a DGV (I did intially try it) 2)There will be logic applied to to the UserControl in the next iteration that will cause the display to be drastically difference in special cases (a weekend for example)

Comment: But in any other case this would be the correct answer, so when my rep goes back up I will send you an upvote